# please rephrase the sql query which is not working

Tags: sql

Can you please help me rephrase the below query (i know its simple, but couldnt figure out).

```
update a
set a.password='sam'
from family_header a,
family_member b 
where 
a.id=b.match_key and
a.username='sam' and
a.pin_code='600061' and
b.dob='1948-10-12'
a.name=b.name;
```

i have the username, pin code from family_header, dob from family_member and matching keys as id with match_key and name in both tables. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be like this:

```
UPDATE family_header
   SET password = 'sam'
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM family_member
                WHERE family_header.id = family_member.match_key
                  AND family_header.name = family_member.name
                  AND family_member.dob = '1948-10-22')
   AND pin_code = '600061'
   AND username = 'sam')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join:

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.PASSWORD = 'sam'
FROM    family_header a
INNER JOIN family_member b ON a.id = b.Match_key
WHERE   a.username = 'sam' AND
        a.pin_code = '600061' AND
        b.dob = '1948-10-12' AND
        a.NAME = b.NAME
```

but i guess you might not need "a.Name = b.Name", since you already have match_key...

Answer (score 0):

The update syntax has to be UPDATE  and you can't use aliases and there isn't a "From" - it's not a select. Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html (this is for MySQL, but T-SQL is fairly generic when it comes to updates and selects)

Assuming you're using MySQL, you use joins in update clauses too:

```
update family_header a
inner join family_member b 
  on a.id = b.match_key
set a.password='sam'
where a.username='sam'
  and a.pin_code='600061'
  and b.dob='1948-10-12'
```

you don't need the *a.name=b.name* - the *a.id = b.match_key* should be sufficient.

Comment: thanks.. this query worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use update with join

```
 update a
 set a.[password]='sam1'
 from #family_header a
     inner join #family_member b on
        a.id=b.match_key and
 a.name=b.name WHERE a.username='sam' and
 a.pin_code='600061' and
 b.dob='1948-10-12'
```

Comment: thanks for your response.. there was some issue with from clause.. however the other answers worked... thanks a lot! :)